# Delimiter to specific column in CSV using dataframes python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

below input table is in CSV file, I need to apply delimiter for code column based on "/" and split the values to other column and number of "/" will varies it is not constant and also output table is mention below I need to achieve that using data frames pandas

input table:

```
date     ctr     code          
12-May   CN      1111/abc/12-e
12-May   CN      1112/abc/wds/12-e
12-May   CN      1113/abc/12-e
```

output table:

```
date     ctr     code     Code1    code2  code3
12-May   CN      1111     abc      12-e
12-May   CN      1112     abc      wds    12-e
12-May   CN      1113     abc      12-e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments in the code for details on the steps:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

# data as a string
text = '''date     ctr     code          
12-May   CN      1111/abc/12-e
12-May   CN      1112/abc/wds/12-e
12-May   CN      1113/abc/12-e'''

# your original data frame
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep=r'\s+')

# split code to new columns (0-based)
df2 = df.code.str.split("/", expand=True)

# rename new columns from 0-base to 1-based
df2 = df2.rename(columns=lambda x: f"code{int(x)+1}")

# join with original dataframe
df2 = df.join(df2)

# drop original code column
df2.drop(columns=['code'], inplace=True)

# test
print(df2)
```

Outputs:

```
     date ctr code1 code2 code3 code4
0  12-May  CN  1111   abc  12-e  None
1  12-May  CN  1112   abc   wds  12-e
2  12-May  CN  1113   abc  12-e  None
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, code working fine but "io.StringIO(text)" I have changed it to "io.StringIO(filepath&filename)" shows empty dataframe. Do you why it is happening?

Comment: @Dev - I don't think you need the `io.StringIO` part at all - that's just so I can see this approach works by using a string input matching your question. In your environment can you use `df = pd.read_csv(filepath&filename, sep=r'\s+')` ?

Comment: df = pd.read_csv(import_path, sep=r'\s+') 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'code'
print(df.head()) below is the result for print statement it apperead with "," delimeter
data,ctr,code
12-May,CN,1111/abc/12-e

Comment: Thanks its working fine, after removing "sep=r'\s+'". Thanks for your help

Comment: Right - if you're using csv then `df = pd.read_csv('./test.csv', sep=',') ` or omit `sep` if default is `,`. If the approach works for you feel free to tick as the answer.